# PHP Curl SFTP no data

Tags: php, curl, web-development-server

I am trying to get a file via sftp. I get the wanted file from 1 root but on another am I getting no file. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
$fh = null;
$c = curl_init($configuri);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($c,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$handle = file_put_contents($file, curl_exec($c));
curl_close($c);
$text = file_get_contents ($file);
```

This is my current CURL code. It works fine for 1 root but not for the other. Any ideas why this is happening? I am logging in as root on both server.

Comment: Do you know what `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);` does?

Comment: Why are you using curl for sftp instead of the recommed method [`ssh2_sftp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)?

Comment: @ahendwh2 https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/sftp/ all day long...